# Polymer Elements - Responsive <body> font size

Tags: css, polymer, polymer-1.0, web-component

I wonder what is the best way to make a Desktop/Mobile page responsive with Polymer Elements' `iron-media-query`? Of course, the CSS could define a responsive behavior with

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width : 768px)
body {font-size: 14px} ...
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 768px) ...
body {font-size: 18px} ...
```

However, Polymer Elements provides the [iron-media-query](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/iron-media-query?view=demo:demo/index.html).

Now, what's better? And most important: How can I apply a responsive font-size for my whole `body` or a specific div's padding with iron-media-query so that the overall font size adjusts (all css elements are defined as x.`em`)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The iron-media-query is mostly to allow binding the result of a query to an element like the paper-drawer-panel that collapses when the screen size is below a certain threshold. 
For global settings just use normal CSS. 
This way fonts and other resources can already be downloaded while Polymer is being initialized.